# jscodeshift PropTypes to proptypes skipping all files in node modules

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, react-proptypes, jscodeshift

I am completely new to backend react setups. Everything was going well until I started styling...I got this

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'object' of undefined
./node_modules/radium/lib/components/style.js
node_modules/radium/lib/components/style.js:23
  20 | displayName: 'Style',
  21 | 
  22 | propTypes: {
> 23 |   radiumConfig: _react.PropTypes.object,
     | ^  24 |   rules: _react.PropTypes.object,
  25 |   scopeSelector: _react.PropTypes.string
  26 | },
```

Upon googling, I landed on the jscodeshift... so I ran

```
% jscodeshift --extensions js -t react-codemod/transforms/React-PropTypes-to-prop-types.js  node_modules/radium/lib/components/ --explicit-require=false
Processing 3 files...
Spawning 3 workers...
Sending 1 files to free worker...
Sending 1 files to free worker...
Sending 1 files to free worker...
All done.
Results:
0 errors
0 unmodified
3 skipped
0 ok
Time elapsed: 0.770seconds
```

I googled some more, and other people had issues with imports e.g material-UI, no returns in the code, or other than js files. I even deleted node modules and reinstalled npm to no avail. I cannot seem to find any solution for my issue.

Here are my package.JSON dependencies...

```
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "@types/react-burger-menu": "^2.6.1",
    "jscodeshift": "^0.9.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "radium": "^0.26.0",
    "react": "^15.6.2",
    "react-burger-menu": "^1.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "yarn": "^1.22.4"
  },
```

Any help is much appreciated.
ps: I am open to completely resetting up the whole project.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling everything fixed this.

I think where I went wrong was probably:
1. Installing or reinstalling packages whose versions were incompatible ie different versions of react-dom and react, etc.
2. Trying too many things at once...

Advice for future googlers: Go slow, especially when converting to TS. Make sure the basic react app is running. Then convert, or add other modules you need, step by step as you migrate to TS.

All the best!